# How can I manage customisation of an Outlook Add-In Manifest?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, manifest, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a Manifest for an Outlook Add-In which contains a few elements that vary from site to site; Microsoft support the ~remoteAppUrl construct, which takes care of most of these cases, but I have two other elements that I'd like to manage in a similar way (if possible?) but that I currently edit manually; these are

- The AppID, which obviously must be different per site
- An App Domain, see below, where XXX is specific to the site

```
<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>https://XXX.azurewebsites.net</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

I know I could have a Manifest per site, but is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the yeoman generator for scaffolding the skeleton of your add-in solution, most probably it will use `webpack` for bundling the source code. In that case you may [configure](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) the `webpack.config.js` file. A `webpack.config.js` file in the root folder will be automatically used by webpack.

Out of the box in the scaffolded solution you get configured release and debug configurations where the manifest file will be patched accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Visual Studio and don't have webpack.config.js; AFAIK, I have to (manually) maintain a separate Manifest per site - unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right avenue.